# Set a default file name/directory for upload on web form by modifying the html

Tags: javascript, html

I use this upload form all of the time and use the same file name each time.
I wonder if there is a way to set the file name in a form by changing the code and saving the file locally. If there other ways to automate this I'd be open to that too.  Thanks.

Here is the source:

```
<html>
<body>

<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="mibdata.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file"/><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood the problem. You tag your question as PHP. Are you displeased with the file name that the user picks?

Answer (score 1):

PHP Code: (in mibdata.php)

```
$target_path = "/path/to/save/file/filename.ext";
if(isset($_FILES['uploadedfile'])){
   move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],$target_path);
}
```

Make sure that the target_path is writable by server.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also have to use something like PHP as a Script so you can move your uploaded file from the Webserver's temp-directory to somewhere where it can be saved persistent.

Look at [this Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) for example.