# Prefilled html file input?

Tags: php, html

So I have a very simple file upload form, code below...

```
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="$theaction" method="POST">
 <input name="source" type="file">
 <input name="message" type="text" value="">
 <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
 </form>
```

I was wondering if I can set with php the source of the file upload? Something like..

```
 <?php $file = "http://mywebsite.com/path/to/img.jpg"; ?>
 <input name="source" type="file" src="<?php echo $file; ?>">
```

I've googled it but I can't come up with anything. I feel like I'm just not using the proper vocabulary, but any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?301528-how-to-set-input-type-file-field-value

Comment: The ability to actually select a file without the user interacting would be a rather large security hole. If you just want to provide a "hint", there is already [a question about that here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17471615/157957), though the lack of answers suggests that's not possible either.

Answer (score 5):

I concur @IMSoP statement.

Instead of populating the input tag value, I would rather create an element (div) to display the thumbnail version of the image that was uploaded by the user that way it makes it clear to the user that a file exist and also I would give them the option to `edit` for uploading a new file & `delete` for deleting the file.